# AWS NFS mount needs to be moved to AZure

Tags: linux, azure, amazon-web-services

read this [mount -t nfs vs cifs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693218/mount-t-nfs-vs-cifs) already :( ?

Our requirement is that we have an application hosted in AWS using nfs-utils to mount a EFS for use ? My question is how can this be done in Azure. I know they have Azure files which works in quite similar way to EFS but as per azure documentation it is done only through cifs-util. Point is that though it will mount a Azure file share in Azure will it work without any issue or do we need to do something in our commands to make it happen?

I am not good in linux, so please pardon me if I am sounding total stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Our requirement is that we have an application hosted in AWS using
>   nfs-utils to mount a EFS for use ? My question is how can this be done
>   in Azure.

Amazon Elastic File System (Amazon EFS) provides simple, scalable file storage for use with Amazon EC2 instances in the AWS Cloud.

If you want do the same thing in Azure, I think you are talking about **Azure storage blob**(new disk).

In Azure, we can via Azure portal to **add a new disk to Azure VM** as a data disk, works like add a physical data disk to a host. Then we can use  `fdisk` to create the file system on the new partition.

We can follow this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/attach-disk-portal#attach-a-new-disk) to attach a new disk to Azure VM via Azure portal.
[image]

After that completed, we can follow this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/classic/attach-disk#initialize-a-new-data-disk-in-linux) to initialize a new data disk in Linux.

[image]

> I know they have Azure files which works in quite similar way to EFS
>   but as per azure documentation it is done only through cifs-util.

You are right, Azure files share works like EFS, but Azure files share use Server Message Block (**SMB**) protocol(also known as Common Internet File System, or CIFS).

The maximum size of an Azure file share is 5 Tib, there is a quota of 20,000 open handles on a single file, and the max IOPS per share is 1000 IOPS.

We can create data disk from Azure storage blob, the maxium size of data disk is 4 Tib(we can create multiple data disks to that VM), and OS disk is 2 Tib.

AWS EFS suppoer Network file system versions 4.0 and 4.1(NFSv4) protocal.

Here a [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-scalability-targets#azure-files-scale-targets) about performance about Azure file share and Azure storage blob.

Comment: Hey Jason, Thanks for the input. Problem is, disk added is limited to particular VM, My requirement is to have shared memory for all the VMs in my network where we will store configs or logs which as per my knowledge is possible with Azure files only. I am also thinking of creating my own NFS server in a vm. Please do let me know If you have any thoughts on my understanding.

Comment: @BlindSniper if you want to share it, we can use Azure file share, we can mount it to multiple VMs. deploy your own NFS server is an option, but we should create two VMs in one availability set to get a high performance(HA). if there is no need high IO or other requirement, maybe Azure file share is the easy way:)

Comment: @BlindSniper yes, azure file share is Smb, not NFS

Comment: Application in focus is programmed to work on NFS mounts so it needs to be checked if it work properly on CIF mounts or not, if not then I may have to go NFS server way !!!!

Comment: @BlindSniper sorry I did not make it clear, Please try it, if you need more help, please let me know:)